# Why is blackberry so unpredictable?

Tags: blackberry

I am currently developing a blackberry java application. In the app, I switch between two screens (let's call them A and B). Now on my simulators (lots of them, OS 5/6/7), the application works fine. On some real devices that I have tested, the application works fine. However on a friend's 9360 OS 7.1.0.336 the app crashes when transitioning from screen A to screen B. I can't duplicate the error on the devices I have or my simulators.After downloading/installing/testing on many simulators, I downloaded a simulator 9800 OS 6.0.0.313 and behold, the app crashes when i transition from screen A to screen B. Now I use eclipse with the blackberry plugin, anytime i try attaching the debugger to this particular simulator i get the attach debugger failed message, or even worse the simulator just "dies" so now i can't even see what is causing the app to crash.. What am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to figure out what was exception:
1. Go to BB home screen
2. Hold ALT (for simulator CTRL on PC is ALT for simulator) key
3. While holding ALT key type LGLG on keyboard

You will see device event log where unhandled exceptions.

Back to main question. It's sometimes really inconsistent. The different OS versions have different issues and sometimes behavior is slightly different. But we can't do anything with it.

Comment: Man thanks a lot.. I eventually figured out what was causing the nullpointer exceptions.. I was adding a customlabelfield class' objects anonymously to a verticalfieldmanager (to fix i had to create referenced instances), i wonder why it works on some devices but not on others.. its really sad that one can't be assured of his/her code to perform as expected on targeted devices.

Comment: @CoolDude I don't know the reason. But the BB UI eats unhandled  exceptions from event thread. On the old devices ti was 100% crash. What I like more.

Comment: i don't know about that but what annoys me is the fact that the SAME code runs perfectly on other devices OS 5/6/7.. but on this particular device and simulator it doesn't.. its this unpredictability that's my problem.